# skew button, un-skew text

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

i have a button which is in a `<a>` tag and i want to skew only the button and not the text

i know i can add `<label>Add to cart</label>` and un-skew it the opposite of the skewed amount but i don't have access to the html but only css.

```
<a role="button" id="add_to_cart" class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Add to Cart</a>
```

and css i did

```
.btn {
transform: skew(10deg);
}
```

is there any way i can un-skew the text inside this button without adding any other tag to the markup?

Comment: add a pseudo element and skew it or create a fancy background. All depend on the final result you want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: Skew a buttons border, not the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768489/css-skew-a-buttons-border-not-the-text)